# Por que a rota não é reconhecida pelo Silex quando há uma barra "/" no final da url requisitada?

Tags: php, silex

Estou começando hoje os meus estudos de MVC com silex, porém estou com dificuldades ao criar rotas acessando os endereços contendo uma barra no final.
Exemplo:

```
http://site.com.br/home/
```

Já consegui o acesso a url somente no caminho `http://site.com.br/home`.

Há alguma forma de acessar o mesmo conteúdo acessando as duas urls?
Segue o código que estou utilizando:

```
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

$app = new Silex\Application();
$app['debug'] = true;

$app->get('/home', function(){
    return  "Você acessou a sua HOME";
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Uma rota definida com uma `/` no final vai coincidir também com um URL sem a `/` no final quando não existir uma rota para o mesmo. Ou tens as duas rotas ou usa apenas uma com a `/` no final e deverás ter o teu problema resolvido.

Comment: Eu gostaria somente de uma solução para acessar /home e /home/ sem ter que criar duas rotas para cada URL

Comment: Se tiveres `$app->get('/home/', function(){` deverá dar-te o mesmo resultado para ambos os URLs: `http://www.example.com/home/` e `http://www.example.com/home`.

Comment: Infelizmente para minha surpresa não foi assim que ocorreu a menos que heja algum procedimento que não tenha seguido.

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade, isso parece ser [um problema conhecido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9792544/allow-trailing-slash-for-symfony2-route-without-params]) entre os utilizadores da biblioteca de rotas do `Symfony`.

Eu uso um framework chamado Laravel que parece conhecer bem esse problema da barra no final da url.

## Usando o HTACCESS

A correção para isso pode ser feita na configuração do `.htaccess` onde, se a url acessada tiver uma barra `/` no final, é redirecionada para url sem a barra no final.

Veja:

```
# Remove a barra do final se não for uma pasta
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Creio que isso já deva bastar para a sua aplicação funcionar corretamente.

Há um pequeno detalhe que deve ser observado quanto a isso: Quando você envia uma requisição do tipo `POST`, o redirecionamento não levará consigo os dados enviados, visto que o redirecionamento se dá em `GET`.

## Modificando REQUEST_URI

Para quem não sabe, as requisições do Silex utilizam internamente a biblioteca  `Symfony Http Foundation`. Através do método `Request::createFromGlobals()` todos os dados da requisição são capturados através das variáveis superglobais (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SERVER`, etc...).

Você pode corrigir facilmente esse problema colocando antes do trecho onde você chama `$app->run()` o seguinte código:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = preg_replace('|/$|', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
```

## Manipulando a propriedade `server` da classe `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`

Depois de rodar alguns testes com o Silex, eu cheguei a conclusão de que a forma mais organizada de resolver o problema é fazendo uma pequena alteração na chamada de `$app->run()`.

Você precisará instanciar `Request`, fazer uma pequena modificação e passá-la como instância de `$app->run()`.

Veja:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$request->server->set('REQUEST_URI', rtrim($request->server->get('REQUEST_URI'), "/"));

$app->run($request);
```

Eu preferi essa última forma já que você não altera o valor da variável super global `$_SERVER`.

**Referências**:

Seu problema também está descrito no Stackoverflow em inglês, em [How to make route "/" ending optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889856/silex-how-to-make-route-ending-optional)

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um comportamento esperado do componente de rotas do Symfony https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/issues/149.

Contudo existe uma página na documentação deles que explica como criar um controle de redirecionamento:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html

Lembre-se de colocar essa rota como a última rota a ser executada (se não existe o risco de erro).

Comment: Seria interessante ter postado parte da solução na sua própria resposta ao invés de ter apenas apontado o link.